# Why does console.dir output a stacktrace on an Error object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-console, console.dir

Today I encountered some behavior that really threw me for a loop while debugging, because at first I really didn't understand what I was looking at. After a lot of trial and error I came to understand that `console.dir` has some unusual behavior with `Error` objects, and I'd like to understand it better.

If you open the Chrome developer console and run `console.dir({a: 1, b: 2})`, you'll see an expandable Object, like so:

[image: chrome developer console]

Expanding the dropdown shows the properties `a` and `b`, plus their values, as expected. On a Promise, the results are similar, although notably the word `Object` is replaced by `Promise`:

[image]

However, with an Error, the results are different:

[image]

Notice now it prints a stacktrace. If you didn't know any better, you'd think you had just printed a string, and you might expect that dropdown arrow to show you more lines of the stacktrace. Of course, instead the dropdown shows you the properties on the object.

But notice that `toString` gives something else, it gives the message but without the stack. If you expand the dropdown, what you see are these properties:

[image]

So it looks like `console.dir` is printing out the Error's `stack` property. But *why*? If `error.toString()` prints the `message` property, then why does `console.dir` instead show the value of the `stack` property, which of course only exists on Error objects? Is `console.dir` hard-coded to treat errors differently than other object classes?

Likewise, `Promise().resolve().toString()` gives `[object Promise]` -- so where is `console.dir` getting the `Promise` string from when you run `console.dir` on a Promise? The behavior here is just unclear and I feel like I might learn something about the internals of *something* if I get a clearer understanding of this behavior.

Comment: "*But why?*" counter question: why *not*? There is no standard to how consoles behave. It's a loose contract that *something* is going to be logged but it's pretty much always implementation dependent when it comes to objects. I'm not sure why a given behaviour should be expected or not.

Comment: By "why" I guess I mean "how"-- if `console.dir` isn't prefacing the expandable property directory with the `toString()` representation, what IS it prefacing it with, and what causes it to differ from one value to the next?

Comment: Devtools formats the output the way it wants. You can override it via *custom formatters*. Here's a random [example](https://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/02/19/custom-chrome-devtools-object-formatters.html).